How to use environment variables in Docker Compose, inside a Spring Boot application?
So I'm working on a Spring Boot application with MySQL. Normally I will load some variables in application.yml file like this
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

The variables will be read from a file named local.env like this
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/todolist
DATABASE_USERNAME=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root

Basically these are for MySQL Workbench (I changed from localhost to mysqldb like the name of MySQL image, since I want to have a MySQL image). And then I have a docker-compose.yml file (both Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are in the same location of local.env) like this
services:
  todo-list:
    image: todo-list:0.0.1
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - ./local.env
    networks:
      - todo-list-network
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 10
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    env_file:
      - ./local.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todolist
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=somerandompassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - todo-list-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      retries: 10
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 30s

volumes:
    mysql-data:

networks:
  todo-list-network:
    name: todo-list-network

I tried to build containers using docker-compose up -d. The mysqldb was created and ran, meanwhile the other container todo-list-todo-list-1 got this kind of error
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)'
I'm not sure if it's because of my configuration or something else, like local.env file. I made changes and tried many ways and the container todo-list-todo-list-1 just got errors and turned off. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Looking at what you posted here your passwords don't match. File root, mysql configuration somerandompassword.
